# How would you determine the length of this line segment tangent to a circle?

Tags: geometry, polygons

So I am working on rebuilding my hot tub siding and want to convert the rounded corners to flat surfaces, but need to determine the width across. Of course the easy answer is measure it, but I wanted to figure it out mathematically and was having trouble figuring it out. It would look something like:

[image]

I'm looking to find the length of the red line. My current measurements put the radius at 6.5 inches. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So you know the radius of the circle (hot tub) and the distance to the corner?

Comment: Looks like a side of a regular octagon circumscribed about the circle. The side-length for that is $2r\sin(\pi/8)$.

Comment: Correct, it's 6.5". I'm not trying to square the corner off though, I'm trying to determine the widest I could make an angled corner around the existing rounded structure.

Comment: So the radius of the circle is $6.5/\sqrt2\approx 4.6$. And then Lord Shark has it.

Comment: So where would $6.5 / \sqrt{2} ≈ 4.6$ fit inside Lord Shark's comment? As it stands their answer comes out to ~4.97, while erachang's answer comes out to ~5.38? If I used it as *r* then it comes out even smaller at ~3.51. Sorry for the formatting, I am unsure how to do that on this section of stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the side of regular $Octagon$:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$2(\sqrt{2}-1)R$

Hint: the diagonal of the square is $\sqrt{2}R$.

Comment: More hint: The distance from the vertex of an isosceles $45^\circ$-$45^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle to the midpoint of the hypotenuse is half the length of the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***

$\tan(\frac {\pi} 4)= \frac x {2h}$

Where $h=R(\sqrt 2 -1)$

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bit of algebraic reasoning to rework the diagram into what you see here:

[image]

Notice the burnt orange dashed lines and their corresponding lengths. Essentially, we’ve broken the red segment into the hypotenuses of two right triangles.  Using the definitions of the trigonometric functions, we get

$$\sin\theta = \frac{r-r\cos\theta}{A}$$
$$\sin\phi = \frac{r-r\sin\phi}{B}$$

There is a plethora of different forms in which you can write this using trigonometric identities, but I will leave that to you.

You said $r = 6.5 \ \mathrm{in}$ and I assume that $\theta=\phi=\frac\pi2=45^\circ$, but this isn’t necessarily true. It is true, however, that $\theta$ and $\phi$ are complementary.

Comment: Thanks for the level of detail, trig has always been my weak spot so I wasn't making the necessary connections there, but this explains the starting steps pretty well.